# iOS Facebook SDK MessageDialog error 202

Tags: ios, facebook, ios8, xcode6

I am trying to set up Facebook sharing with FBSDK in my iOS app.

I have been reading the documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios), and currently have

```
[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:self];
```

working with a content object - `FBSDKShareLinkContent`.

However, upon trying to use the similar method as specified for Facebook Messenger sharing,

```
[FBSDKMessageDialog showWithContent:content delegate:self];
```

i am getting a crash. I caught the error and logged it in one of the delegate methods, and it states "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.share error 202.)
"

I have searched for this specific error but have not found anything directly with the same error. Here is full code

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:kAPPShareLink];
content.contentDescription = kAPPShareDescription;
content.contentTitle = kAPPShareTitle;

if (buttonIndex == 0) {
    // Facebook

    [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:self];
} else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
    // Facebook Messenger

    [FBSDKMessageDialog showWithContent:content delegate:self];
}
```

Forgive me if i am missing something obvious, but as [this documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios) reads, i assume the `FBSDKMessageDialog showWithContent:` method would work the same way as `FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:` which is working for me.

- I am using the latest version of XCode with iOS8.

Comment: I couldn't repro the error. Which version of Facebook Messenger app do you use? Do you get switched to the Messenger app? Facebook SDK includes RPSSample project, can you repro with that project?

Comment: Just got the same error. Did you resolve this problem?

Comment: Not resolved. I encountered this using a custom button but thereafter changed to UIActivitySheet

Answer (score 6):

I had to login and then Post , that is how it worked :

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];


[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
{

    if (error)
    {
    // Process error
    }
    else if (result.isCancelled)
    {
        // Handle cancellations
    }
    else
    {
        FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
        content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://developers.facebook.com/"];

        FBSDKMessageDialog *messageDialog = [[FBSDKMessageDialog alloc] init];
        messageDialog.delegate = self;
        [messageDialog setShareContent:content];

        if ([messageDialog canShow])
        {
            [messageDialog show];
        }
        else
        {
            // Messenger isn't installed. Redirect the person to the App Store.
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/facebook-messenger/id454638411?mt=8"]];
        }

    }
}];
```

and the Share Delegate :

```
- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results
{
    NSLog(@"didCompleteWithResults");
}

- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError ::: %@" , error);
}

- (void)sharerDidCancel:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer
{
    NSLog(@"sharerDidCancel");
}
```

Edit:

[messageDialog canShow] returns NO on the iPad, works fine on iPhone

Posted the issue on [Facebook Developers forum](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/389140797915569/?comment_id=826349080784950).

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am no longer implementing the code in my application to test with, but if anyone else uses this please confirm and i will give accepted answer

Comment: I used it in one of my apps, but dont know if anyone else does.

Comment: I managed to implement it and it's working until the [messageDialog canShow]. It skips to else, but I think that is because I'm running it on Simulator. Can you elaborate if I can test sending messages on simulator? Otherwise it works perfectly.

Comment: @Septronic - Sorry you wont be able to test it on the simulator as you cannot install the messenger app on it. You will need an iOS device with FB messenger installed to send any message.

Comment: @aks5686 Thanks  bunch dude, I'll try it on my phone and see how it goes :)

Comment: Such idiocy that `canShow` returns `NO`. I should have read the whole answer, it would have saved me hours :( FBSDK gives me tears and ages me every time I use it.

Answer (score 2):

I was stuck with this for a while and in the end realised that I had not added `fb-messenger-share-api` under `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in the `info.plist` file. Just putting this here in case it helps someone. Thanks :)

> **N.B.** It is `fb-messenger-share-api` and not `fb-messenger-api`.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: This fits more as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation yet to post comments*

I get the same error, both Facebook and messenger are updated.

I checked my permissions with

```
[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] permissions]
```

and I think I have enough:

```
"contact_email",
"publish_stream",
"user_likes",
"publish_checkins",
"video_upload",
"create_note",
"basic_info",
"publish_actions",
"public_profile",
"photo_upload",
"status_update",
email,
"user_friends",
"share_item"
```

I tried the same way as OP, and also I tried that:

```
FBSDKMessageDialog *messageDialog = [[FBSDKMessageDialog alloc] init];
[messageDialog setShareContent:content];
messageDialog.delegate = self;

if ([messageDialog canShow]) {
    [messageDialog show];        
}
```

`[messageDialog canShow]` returns **NO**, and the delegate methods catch the fail with the 202 error described by the OP.

I tried using the FBSDKSendButton, and doesn't seem to work either.

On the other hand, FBSDKShareDialog works perfectly...

I hope this helps to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

*This bubbled up again in an interweb search.* Nowadays, there is a simple answer for the error `Message dialog is not available` with code `202`:

[Facebook's documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios):

> Note: Currently the message dialog is not supported on iPads.