# open facebook messanger using FBMessageDialog iphone sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook

```
FBSDKMessageDialog * shareDialog = [[FBSDKMessageDialog alloc] init];

FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];

content.contentDescription =@"HELLO";

content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://202.258.69.3"];

shareDialog.shareContent = content;
shareDialog.delegate = self;

[FBSDKMessageDialog showWithContent:content delegate:self];
```

It always provided me error like as following

> -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fb-messenger-api:/" - error: "(null)" description :: The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (com.facebook.sdk.share error 202.)

Comment: Are you logged in? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29364157/ios-facebook-sdk-messagedialog-error-202

Comment: Have you updated the info.plist with the proper keys?

Answer (score 0):

From the error, I am guessing it is due to one of the two reasons:

1. the user was not able to get authenticated, make sure you have added the `FacebookAppID` key in the `info.plist` file
2. try including keys `fbauth` and `fbauth2` in `info.plist` under the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`